# Primality test involving Wilson's theorem not working as planned

Tags: c

I'm just getting started with programming and I've run into a problem I can't seem to figure out. I've written this function, `isPrime` that seems to always pass the equality test. I can confirm that the `factorial` function works because I had separately tested it.

Wilson's theorem states that a number p is prime if (p - 1)! + 1 is a multiple of p.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void isPrime(double p);
double factorial(double n);

int main(void) {
    double userInput;
    while(1) {
        scanf("%lf", &userInput);
        isPrime(userInput);
    }
    return 0;
}

//

double factorial(double n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return n;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

void isPrime(double p) {
    if(modf(factorial(p - 1) + 1, &p) == 0)
        printf("Prime!\n");
    else
        printf("Not prime!\n");
}
```

Comment: Did you try printing what you received? (`printf("%lf Prime!\n", p)`)

Comment: This code is not suitable for primality testing of large numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use doubles to hold integers. Roundoff error will make tests for equality completely bogus. See "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating Point](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)".

Comment: I need this to work with extremely large numbers, larger than what an int can hold. Thanks for the link by the way!

Comment: @isosine, use `unsigned long long` for large unsinged integers. Using `double` is completely useless.

Comment: @isosine: if you use `double` your extremely large numbers will be approximated, so your test will be completely meaningless. You may want to use some big integer library (e.g. GMP).

Answer (score 3):

`double` can't accurately store the factorials if n is larger than 23 or so. From then on, your results will be completely bogus. If you want to use Wilson's theorem for primality testing, use modular arithmetic,

```
uint64_t modFactorial(uint64_t n, uint64_t m) {
    uint64_t f = 1;
    for(; n > 1; --n) {
        f = (n*f) % m;
    }
    return f;
}

int isPrime(uint64_t p) {
    if (p < 2) return 0;
    return modFactorial(p-1,p) + 1 == p;
}
```

That can correctly handle input smaller than 2^32. However, it's rather slow, Wilson's theorem is not a good way to test primality in practice, its value lies in applications in number theory.

If you need to handle *large* integers, use GMP (that comes with - probabilistic - primality testing).

Answer (score 1):

`modf` doesn't perform modulus like you expect it to. To quote:

```
 The modf() break value into integral and fractional parts, each of which
 has the same sign as the argument.  They return the fractional part, and
 store the integral part (as a floating-point number) in the object
 pointed to by iptr
```

You want [`fmod`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fmod/) and friends instead of `modf`.

Comment: Oh wow, I hadn't realized there was another function like that. What a mix-up. Anyway, thank you very much! That seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small mistake in your code.

Change the test to the following:

```
if (modf((factorial(p - 1) + 1)/p, &p) == 0)
```

Also, as others have pointed out its probably not the best idea to be using doubles.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that your factorial function is returning 0 because (n <= 1) allows n = 0 to be returned.